# Extendscript parse unicode characters into text layer

Tags: unicode, extendscript, after-effects

I'm trying to write a script that parses an array of characters into subsequent keyframes of a text layer in After Effects. Everything works. Only I'd like to change the function to read unicode instead of normal text.

Here's my Code for the Script:

```
var textLayer = currentComp.layers.addText("test");
        textLayer.name = "score";
        textLayer.position.setValue([50,500]);

        //Chose the txt with the array
        var myFile = File.openDialog("Navigate to keyframe file.");
        myFile.open("r");

        var myLine = myFile.readln();
        var keyValues = myLine.split(",")

        var prop1 = app.project.item(1).layer(1).property("ADBE Text Properties").property("ADBE Text Document");

        var arrayLength = keyValues.length;

    //Keyframe Loop
    app.beginUndoGroup("Keys");

        for(var i=0; i<arrayLength; i++){
        prop1.setValueAtTime([i]/25,keyValues[i]);
        }
    app.endUndoGroup();
```

And this is the String that i'm trying to parse:

```
\u5c07,\u63a2,\u8a0e,\u53ca,\u5176,\u4ed6
```

These are all unicode characters.

Comment: Could you boil your code snippet down so somebody without the font and without a text file can execute it? Or at least provide the file or a string you are trying to parse?

Comment: @fabiantheblind done :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played a bit with your code. I also was not able to read the unicode characters from the file. What worked is storing the data in a JSON format and parsing it. (get the parser here https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)
See my modified code below.

This is the data as JSON

```
["\u5c07","\u63a2","\u8a0e","\u53ca","\u5176","\u4ed6"]
```

This is the modified script

```
#include "json2.js"
// use json parsers
// get it here https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js
var main = function() {
  var currentComp = app.project.items.addComp("test", 800, 600, 1, 10, 25); // add a comp
  var textLayer = currentComp.layers.addText("test");
  textLayer.name = "score";
  textLayer.position.setValue([50, 500]);

  //Chose the JSON with the array
  var myFile = File.openDialog("Navigate to keyframe file.");
  if (myFile === null) return;  // stop if user cancels
  myFile.open("r"); 
  var content = myFile.read();// read the whole file
  var keyValues = JSON.parse(content);// parse its content, dont use eval
  // rest is as before
  var prop1 = app.project.item(1).layer(1).property("ADBE Text Properties").property("ADBE Text Document");
  // var arrayLength = keyValues.length; // dont need this
  //Keyframe Loop
  app.beginUndoGroup("Keys");
  for (var i = 0; i < keyValues.length; i++) {
    prop1.setValueAtTime([i] / 25, keyValues[i]);
  }
  app.endUndoGroup();
}
main();
```

Comment: hi fabian, the script works perfectly, but I ran into problems with japanese (utf-16 if i understood it right) characters like "\u3402\ue0101". The standard encoding in json seems to be utf-8 (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627#section-3) I coundt find out how to change it. Maybe you have an idea? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe reading them like this helps? `keyValues[0].toString(16)`

Comment: hmm, doesnt seem to work. the console logs : `㐂0,㐂1,㐂2,㕗,㕘,㕙,㕠,㕡` 
I changed the script to: `prop1.setValueAtTime([i] / 25, keyValues[i].toString(16));` thats right is it?

Comment: Yeah that's right. But it was just a wild guess. Maybe the file encoding can help you.